# Display manager login loop

Tags: linux, bash, debian, xorg

I am running Debian Stretch and am no longer able to log into the desktop. First, applications began to close unexpectedly. Shortly after that, I started experiencing screen artifacts. After rebooting, I tried to log in. The screen went black and the login screen showed up again. No matter how many times I tried to log in, it wouldn't work. However, when I tried to log in as root, it worked.

I went into a `tty` via `CTRL+ALT+F2` and instead of showing `username@host:~$` on the shell, it shows `-bash-4.4$`.

If I run `startx` as a non-root user, I get the same black screen behavior. If I run it as root, I can get to the desktop.

I started looking into `Xorg` logs and found this error: `xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)`.

I tried 3 different users: the root user and two non-root, sudo-able users, but the only user that made it to the desktop was root.

I also tried `chmod u+s` on `xorg` and `xinit` to no avail.

I am not low on disk space.

When the system was working I was using `lightdm` and `gnome`. I uninstalled both and reinstalled `lightdm` and `xfce4`, and now am using `lightdm` and `xfce4`.

I believe the issue is caused by my bash profile not loading correctly, but I don't know much about that process. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: On the login screen select a specific desktop environment to load as opposed to leaving it as default or last-used.

Comment: The issue occurs regardless of the desktop session/environment I choose.